Cayley Transform (Möbius Transform)
The Cayley Transform maps the real line to the unit circle, and:
"Furthermore, since $f$ is continuous and $i$ is taken to $0$ by $f$, the upper half-plane is mapped to the unit disk."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Complex_homography
I don't understand how this conclusion about the mapping of the upper half-plane follows immediately from $f$ being continuous.
Why is this true, and how do you prove it rigorously?

Of course continuity is not enough. You should not always trust Wikipedia articles since anybody can edit these.

@MoisheKohan, what’s wrong with Wikipedia’s explanation? OP quoted only the last sentence. In general Wikipedia is quite reliable. Allowing anyone to edit actually improves it.

@Deane: one needs a homeomorphism not just continuity

@MoisheKohan, I’m probably being dumb but if you interpret “map to the unit disk” as meaning the image is in the unit disk, isn’t that enough? In any case, it’s easy to find the formula for the inverse.

@Deane: Of course, but the point I am making is that one can easily find continuous maps of the compactified upper half-plane sending the extended real line to the unit circle, sending $i$ to $0$ but whose image is strictly larger than the closed unit disk. Thus, continuity is not enough in order to make the conclusion stated in the Wikipedia article.  What one needs is a homeomorphism (if one is to argue topologically or via real analysis) or a holomorphic map.

@MoisheKohan, it's probably worth editing the wikipedia article.

The Cayley transform is an automorphism of the entire Riemann sphere. It sends $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ to the unit circle. You can either check this fact directly or use the fact that "generalized circles" (i.e. circles in the plane or lines in the plane plus infinity) are permuted under Möbius transformations along with the fact $\{\infty, 1, -1\}$ gets sent to $\{1, -i, i\}$, and three distinct points define a generalized circle.
Both $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus (\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\})$ and $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus S^1$ have two connected components, and since the Cayley transform is a auto-homeomorphism of the Riemann sphere it must map a given connected component in $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus (\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\})$ (either the upper or lower half plane) homeomorphically to one of the connected components of $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus S^1$ (either the open unit disc or the set $\{z \in \mathbb{C}  : |z| > 1\} \cup \{\infty\})$. So the only remaining question is which component maps to which. However, we can check directly that $i$ gets mapped to $0$, which is inside the unit disc, so the upper half plane must be mapped homeomorphically onto the open unit disc.

Thank you for the explanation. As a follow up question:

Would continuity and bijectivity be enough to conclude that the upper half plane is mapped to the unit circle?
The line of reasoning:
Because it is injective, we can consider the transform as a map from $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus (\mathbb{R} \cup {\infty})$ to $\hat{\mathbb{C}} \setminus S^1$. The two connected components then have to be mapped to only one of the connected components in the codomain because of continuity. Lastly, surjectivity implies that they  have to mapped to different components, and that they must "fill up" the entire connected component they are mapped to.

@klingeron Yes, that should be sufficient.

There is certainly some ambiguity in the phrasing of the question... :)
I myself would find an interesting version of the question as "(why?) does the Cayley transform bi-holomorphically map the upper half-plane to the unit disk" (or vice-versa)... and "in what context is this 'obvious'?" :)
One form of the "obviousness" might follow from the idea/fact that circles-and-lines in the Riemann sphere are mapped to the same things under all linear fractional ("Mobius"?) transformations/maps. And lines/circles are determined exactly by three points on them (with $\infty$ for straight lines). So we can just track any three appealing points to see that the circle and real line are swapped... and, then, some mild topological arguments probably hand-wave the rest... :)
At the same time, with the Cayley transform, it is quite easy to do the computation that says the imaginary part of the image of the unit disk is positive, and vice-versa, etc. In fact, such an argument is standard, and greatly generalized (to "classical domains", as discussed by Siegel and others).
